# I used mat-table in angular 6 application to display the data but the result is coming as empty spaces

Tags: angular

I used the MatTable from the angular material module but unable to display the data in the table. The spaces are coming for the table instead of the rows, but i am able to get the results in my console.All the imports are done.

Below is the component.ts file in which the issues are initialise with the Issues interface's array and IssueService is getting injected in the constructor, from which getIssues is getting called.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

import { Issue } from '../../issue.model';


import { IssueService } from '../../issue.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  issues: Issue[];
  displayedColumns: ['title','responsible','severity','status','actions'];

  constructor(private issueService: IssueService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.fetchIssues();
  }

  fetchIssues(){
    this.issueService.getIssues().subscribe((data: Issue[])=>{
      this.issues=data;
      console.log("get service call");
      console.log(this.issues);
    });
  }
}
```

Below is the components.html file to display the table

```
<div>
    <br>
    <mat-card>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/create">Create New Issue</button>
      <br><br>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <br>
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="issues" >
        <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.title}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="responsible">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Responsible</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.responsible}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="severity">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Severity</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.severity}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.status}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-column-right">Actions</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="mat-column-right">
            <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="editIssue(element._id)">Edit</button>
            <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="deleteIssue(element._id)">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

      </table>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
```

[This is the displayed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vSy3.png)

Comment: Check "displayedColumns" and "Issue" model same or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with displayedColumns property syntax. change it to below.

displayedColumns: string[] =['title','responsible','severity','status','actions'];